# what is this topic "__consumer_offsets" in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

When I run this command, I get 2 topics. I know I created the test topic but I see an additional topic called "__consumer_offsets". 
From the name it implies that it is related to consumer offsets, but how is it being used?

`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
__consumer_offsets
test`

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181
Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
                      *
                      *
                      *
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

This is happening in Kafka 1.1.0 and why there are 50 partitions.
Also looking for a way to disable this because every time I try to run "describe" the topics, first it prints the 50 partitions of the __consumer_offsets and then prints my topics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of \_\_consumer\_offsets and \_schema topics in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529511/what-is-the-use-of-consumer-offsets-and-schema-topics-in-kafka)

Comment: You can look at it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925866/kafka-how-to-read-from-consumer-offsets-topic

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529511/what-is-the-use-of-consumer-offsets-and-schema-topics-in-kafka partially addresses the question. I don't even see the _schema topic.

Answer (score 5):

In initial versions of Kafka, offset was being managed at zookeeper, but Kafka has continuously evolved over the time introducing lot of new features. Now Kafka manages the offset in an internal/system level topic i.e. __consumer_offsets.

Whenever you create a topic without specifying the number of partitions explicitly , Kafka ends up creating 50 partitions by default for that topic. Same implies to the topic __consumer_offsets.

Answer (score 2):

consumers store the last consumed message offset id in kafka topic `__consumer_offsets` based on the consumer group id.
This enables different consumers(obviously with different consumer id) to process the next message after the last consumed message and avoid duplicate message processing.

Comment: Any idea why there are 50 partitions

Comment: The number of partitions is determined by `offsets.topic.num.partitions` option in Kafka configuration. 50 is the default, but you can change it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "to avoid duplicates" because by default, you still get at least once delivery and if offsets aren't committed after being processed, you will get duplicates... Rather the offsets are primarily stored for recovery/checkpointing

Answer (score 2):

The topic `__consumer_offsets` is used by consumers to store the offsets of message that's they read. It enable recovery when a consumer restart it will read the last position that it consume before the it went down et processing the next offset.

@cricket_007 was right, you can have duplicate by default in Kafka, it's the at least once semantics that's used.

Answer (score 0):

> What is `__consumer_offsets` ?

Kafka uses its own compacted internal topic, called `__consumer_offsets`, which relates directly to your consumer offsets themselves.

> How is it being used?

Kafka does not need a history of offsets that a consumer group consumes; it just needs the latest offset. By storing the offsets in a compacted topic, the log, in effect, gets an updated view of the current state of its world.

**Example:** Imagine friends reading a book together. Instead of writing page numbers on paper, they use a notebook, where each writes their page number. Over time, it gets cluttered. Similar to Kafka topics, where each offset (page number) is a new entry. Now, imagine they use a whiteboard, erasing old numbers and writing new ones. This is like compacted Kafka topics, storing only the latest offset for each consumer group, making retrieval faster

> Why there are 50 partitions for `__consumer_offsets`?

Default partition count for `__consumer_offsets` topic: 50 partitions.

**Calculation:** Kafka considers total partitions of consumed topics (N). Partition count for `__consumer_offsets` topic is:

```
partition_count = max(N, 50)
```