# Kafka Streams API with Users topic (Predefined topic)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there any way that i can use kafka stream api with predefined users topic but able to call functions like through() & to(), per my understanding these functions will generate intermediate topics for caching purposes.

Comment: Check out the docs: http://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html -- topic uses in `through()` and `to()` should be pre-created.

Answer (score 1):

You require a pre-defined topic as your input source.

`through()` is the only action you listed that makes an "intermediate" topic.
`to()` makes a terminal topic.

If you don't do stateful operations or repartitioning (by altering the message key), there are no intermediate topics.

More info - [What are internal topics used in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080896/what-are-kafka-internal-topics-used)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have read these articles earlier and the only thing i can't figure out is how do we create some of the topics ein advance.

Comment: Have you never created a topic? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_createtopic Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851426/2308683

Comment: I am referring to internal topics

Comment: Internal topics are created when the broker starts. And they're made using the above methods. I don't understand. There is no internal users topic

Comment: i would like to perform joining and aggregations via stream apis with "users topics" alone (with no privilege to be granted for creating internal topics), however i realised the followings.It'll be helpful if you have any other better ways to bypass generation of internal topics.

Changelog topics are created when there are join/aggregation operations on the stream. Actually the result of aggregation call creates a state store and for fault-tolerance the state store is backed up by a Kafka Changelog topic. The aggregation results are stored into this internal topic.

Comment: Again, there is no "users topic" that exists, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: you can refer to this site regarding definitions of user topics https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html

Comment: Okay, that just means a topic created by a user, following the above methods I already mentioned.