# The meaning of the content of the __consumer_offsets topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka-dump-log tool to see the content of the __consumer_offsets topic. Can someone explain what does that content mean exactly ( offset, createtime, isvalid, keysize, valuesize, compresscodec, producerId, producerEpoch, isTransactional, headerKeys, key, offset, payload ) ?

```
[root@localhost kafka_2.11-2.0.0]# bin/kafka-dump-log.sh --files data/kafka/__consumer_offsets-32/00000000000000036360.log --value-decoder-class "kafka.serializer.StringDecoder" --offsets-decoder
    Dumping data/kafka/__consumer_offsets-32/00000000000000036360.log
    Starting offset: 36360
    offset: 36360 position: 0 CreateTime: 1623678492136 isvalid: true keysize: 19 valuesize: 28 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: 0 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: offset::b0147:test:48 payload: 35
    offset: 36361 position: 0 CreateTime: 1623678492136 isvalid: true keysize: 19 valuesize: 28 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: 1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: offset::b0147:test:64 payload: 34
    offset: 36362 position: 0 CreateTime: 1623678492136 isvalid: true keysize: 19 valuesize: 28 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: 2 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: offset::b0147:test:14 payload: 34
    ...
    offset: 36460 position: 5497 CreateTime: 1623678503139 isvalid: true keysize: 9 valuesize: 24 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: {"metadata":"b0147"} payload: {"protocolType":"consumer","protocol":null,"generationId":2,"assignment":"{}"}
    offset: 36461 position: 5598 CreateTime: 1623678554656 isvalid: true keysize: 19 valuesize: -1 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: []
    ...
```

Comment: why is there `32` suffix in `__consumer_offsets-32`. Important for me to understand this... if some one knows please answer.

Comment: does it mean - partition 32.. hoping so.

Answer (score 6):

The fields you see are not specific to `__consumer_offsets`, they are just the metadata about each message/batch in the log and you will get them for all topics, see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#recordbatch

If you want to explore the content of `__consumer_offsets` you need to know that it contains 2 types of records:

- OffsetMetadata: this is information about the offsets committed by groups
- GroupMetadata: this is information about members of consumer groups

To show OffsetMetadata, you can use:

```sh
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets
```

To show GroupMetadata, you can use:

```sh
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$GroupMetadataMessageFormatter" \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets
```

Comment: Good answer. Will complement with the usage of that particular topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529511/what-is-the-use-of-consumer-offsets-and-schema-topics-in-kafka#:~:text=__consumer_offsets%20is%20used%20to,only%20latest%20offsets%20information%20available.

Comment: I tried your last command but I get an empty result. Why?
# bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh   --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$GroupMetadataMessageFormatter" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets
^CProcessed a total of 200 messages

Comment: Do you have any existing consumer groups? Is the other command working?

Comment: why is there `32` suffix in `__consumer_offsets-32`. Important for me to understand this... if someone knows please answer.

Comment: does it mean - partition 32.. hoping so.

Comment: yes after the dash there is the partition number